# Powerpoint "remembering" a choice

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I've created a game show with questions and prizes. The contestants will answer a question, and then pick a "box".

There are 5 boxes I have triggered to individually disappear once clicked. So a contestant picks box 1, box 1 disappears revealing a prize, then on to the next slide and question.

Is there a way powerpoint can "remember" box 1 was clicked so if I hyperlink back to the slide, box 1 is no longer available...or at least has a red x over it?

...Or can I copy and paste the "boxes slide" and write some vba to place an x over a box on all the copied slides once it's clicked?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If it's enough to just hide the text in the box, you can change the color for visited hyperlinks.  Click the Design tab in the ribbon.  Under the Variants section, click the dropdown arrow in the bottom-right.  Select Colors -> Customize Colors, then under "Followed hyperlink" choose a color that blends in with your background.

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem, but it's something I didn't know could be done. Thanks!